# Getting data from dropdown list javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my first time at this. I'm trying to create a script that has some dropdown options. I need to get the value from the last dropdown, then I need to multiply that value with the input number.

I have still not created the input number because I don't know how to get the data from the price. 
Basically when it shows the price, I need this price to be able to have input number area to multiply with the price.

My fiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/blaxxzg/sy95ksnL/

```
var stateObject = {
    "Mali format": {
        "2/5 cm": ["9,5 €"],
    },
    "Mali format-tanki": {
        "1/3,5 cm": ["12,13 €"],
    },
    "Veliki format": {
        "3/7 cm": ["20,15 €"],
    },
    "Veliki format-tanki": {
        "2/4 cm": ["18,79 €"],
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    var stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel"),
        countySel = document.getElementById("countySel"),
        citySel = document.getElementById("citySel");
    for (var state in stateObject) {
        stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
    }

    stateSel.onchange = function () {
        countySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
          countySel.options[0].text = "Prvo odaberite tip kamena"
          citySel.options[0].text = "Prvo odaberite debljinu kamena"
          return; // done   
        }  
        countySel.options[0].text = "Please select county"
        for (var county in stateObject[this.value]) {
            countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(county, county);
        }
        if (countySel.options.length==2) {
          countySel.selectedIndex=1;
          countySel.onchange();
        }  

    }
    stateSel.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded

    countySel.onchange = function () {
        citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
          citySel.options[0].text = "Please select county first"
          return; // done   
        }  
        citySel.options[0].text = "Please select city"

        var cities = stateObject[stateSel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(cities[i], cities[i]);
        }
        if (citySel.options.length==2) {
          citySel.selectedIndex=1;
          citySel.onchange();
        }  

    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Here is an update of your fiddle. Let me know if this is what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/rrnufjyt/1/

Comment: Yes that is what i was looking for. Thank you very much. @VijendraKulhade

Comment: Can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the solution you are looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/rrnufjyt/1/)
I have added the onchange for last dropdown.

```
citySel.onchange = function(){
document.getElementById('PicExtPrice').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, i just added 3 boxes, box 1 is showing citysel and thats ok but how to multiply box1 with box2 (box2 has to be free input of numbers) then to show in result box maybe you can help here also? https://jsfiddle.net/blaxxzg/sy95ksnL/4/